# It is possible to create a insert trigger inside a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I want to create a insert trigger that checks the valid data(calculating on sql server by taking the values from user)before insertion takes place.So i perform the calculations on stored procedure and now if data are valid then i want trigger fired.Is it possible ? if possible is it good practice?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to have a stored procedure that validates the data and then inserts. Then... have a stored procedure that validates the data and then inserts, why does it have to be a trigger? Your application calls the stored procedure instead of inserting onto the table.

While technically what you ask for is possible with an [INSTEAD OF INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175089.aspx) trigger, that doesn't mean you should do it.